# AngularJS default route missing slash before #

Tags: angularjs

when i run my app locally and I enter localhost my otherwise route handles this and directs to localhost/#/clips.  However, when deployed to dev the app lives in a sub directory (http://appServer.com/theApp) and the otherwise route creates http://appServer.com/theApp#/clips.  I've been searching for an answer to this for a couple days.  What am I missing?

Comment: And it does not load your app?

Comment: no, it should evaluate to http://appServer.com/theApp/#/clips but its going to http://appServer.com/theApp#/clips.

Comment: One workaround to make it load is to set a base in your html when you deploy.  Paste this into the <head>.  <base href="/theApp/" />  There may be a better way (which I'd also like to hear).